# Compare two html files

Tags: java, html, compare

Hi
I want to compare code of two HTML files. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe it should be on http://superuser.com ?

Answer (score 4):

If you can use a tool; there are a lot of compare-tools available like [UltraCompare](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultracompare.html).
But if you want to build it yourself; please let us know.

**Edit:** There is a [Java library available](http://code.google.com/p/daisydiff/) for this.

Comment: I would like to build it, using Java :)

Comment: I have the HTML code as string, is it possible to extract the differences using DaisyDiff?

Answer (score 2):

I use [winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) when I'm on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Unix platform, you can compare the two files using a program such as [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff).

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically or just in an editor?

On Windows, use [Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/). On a Mac, use [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/).